# When would I use docker-compose's "--service-ports" flag?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker-compose's run reference includes the "--service-ports" flag.

```
 --service-ports       Run command with the service's ports enabled and mapped
                      to the host.
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

The description doesn't really tell me anything. Ports are mapped to the host on `docker-compose up` if I specify them in the docker-compose file. No matter if the flag is used or not.

What is it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Docker documentation:

> `docker-compose run` runs a one-time command against a service. [...]
>
> Commands you use with `run` start in new containers with configuration defined by that of the service, including volumes, links, and other details. However, there are two important differences.
>
> First, the command passed by `run` overrides the command defined in the service configuration. [...]
>
> The second difference is that the `docker-compose run` command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host, specify the --service-ports flag:
>
> `docker-compose run --service-ports web python manage.py shell`
>
> Alternatively, manual port mapping can be specified with the `--publish` or `-p` options, just as when using docker run:
>
> `docker-compose run --publish 8080:80 -p 2022:22 -p 127.0.0.1:2021:21 web python manage.py shell`

This is meant so that you can run singular commands against an already defined service or services using `docker-compose run`.

For example, lets say you set up a compose file that defines some kind of service. To start the service to run in the background you use `docker-compose -f <FILE> up --detach` but if you wanted to look inside the container using a terminal, you would run `docker-compose run bash`.

The reason for the ports being ignored is `docker-compose run` assumes the container is already set up, and has it's ports set up correctly. If you ran a script that did something involving ports using `docker-compose run /path/to/script.sh` you might not want it to change the ports that were correctly mapped with your `docker-compose up` command. This way, the option makes it so you have to tell docker explicitly "I actually want port mappings to change".

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for explaining!